# React beautiful dnd - Invalid hook call

Tags: reactjs

So recently I started integrating React beautiful dnd into my React project, I wrote a bunch of code and got this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

And this:

```
The above error occurred in the <DragDropContext> component:

at DragDropContext (http://127.0.0.1:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8960:19)
at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior
```

I tried playing around with code, but it didn't help, I created new project and it turns out I get this error with something simple like THAT:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const App = () =>  {
  const onDragEnd = () => {};

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Droppable droppableId={0}>
        {() => (
          <ul>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
          </ul>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: I tried your code in codesandbox it's not giving me any errors  check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-pqgztu?file=/index.js)

Comment: @monim check the console, try to refresh the page, i got the error "react-beautiful-dnd
A setup problem was encountered.
> Invariant failed: A Droppable requires a droppableId prop
‍ This is a development only message. It will be removed in production builds." even if i see the rendered 1-2-3 list

Comment: Yes, you get this error, which is not an error to worry about. I'm talking about  `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call.`  it doesn't appear

Comment: @monim Yeah, but you said "it's not giving me any errors" and i just pointed there will be an error, but different from what was asked in question. Probably i misunderstood you.

Comment: yeah, You're right. I didn't make it clear sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You should check browser's console, `react-beautiful-dnd` logs messages about errors in the console instead of throwing errors to UI error overlay.

Issues: `droppableId={0}` expects a string, for `{0}` it will log an error:

> Invariant failed: A Droppable requires a droppableId prop

Replacing it with string will produce the next error:

> Invariant failed:
> provided.innerRef has not been provided with a HTMLElement.
> You can find a guide on using the innerRef callback functions at:
> https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/using-inner-ref.md

So the code that will not throw errors:

```
import React from "react";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

const App = () => {
  const onDragEnd = () => {};

  return (
    <DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <Droppable droppableId={"123"}>
        {(provided, snapshot) => (
          <ul ref={provided.innerRef}>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
          </ul>
        )}
      </Droppable>
    </DragDropContext>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Also, `react-beautiful-dnd` has a nice [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k260nyxq9v?file=/index.js) example.

Comment: The problem is not with hardcoded droppableId value, dnd plugin logs nothing into console, I just see an "Invalid hook call" error and nothing gets rendered. I have no idea why this happens, also there are almost no info about this error in google :(

Comment: @Daniil456 Well my answer is only about the 2nd part of your original question, sadly, for the first part i can only recommend detaching (commenting out) one component after another in JSX to isolate the component that throws the error about `invalid hook call`, if you show the listing of that file - we will be able to help.

Comment: It's DragDropContext component throwing error. Also [here](https://pastebin.com/rEDnNh4p) is full log in console. And [here](https://pastebin.com/fUL5iF4Q) is what `>npm ls react` returns - perhaps the problem is related to that? Sadly, I don't know what "listing of file" means

Comment: @Daniil456 Listing i mean just the code of a component you have. Also, it only shows that `DragDropContext` is throwing an error, this lib somewhy uses a different  components composition and execution flows from what you would expect from classic react app, So i guess you will need to provide us either the code of your ocmponents, from up to down, thats why i asked you to isolate the faulty component and show it to us, either ot provide a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-dew-p34xb2?file=/src/App.js) example so we can elaborate.

Comment: I replaced my code with code from your answer and I still get this error, it looks like the problem is not with code, but with my environment : (

Comment: @Daniil456 Im sorry to hear that, but if by any chance you figure out what was the issue - write the answer for your question here, maybe someone will find it helpful